# Google chrome keeps redirecting localhost to github OAuth login

Tags: google-chrome, github, oauth, jenkins

I'm currently using Jenkins, and I wanted to authorize the Github access by using the OAuth plugin. So, I added the needed "Client ID" and "Client Secret" via Github's page to Jenkins to ensure that Jenkins and Github were talking to each other.

After this the Jenkins and Github handshake (via Oauth I believe) got stuck in some kind of infinite loop, so I decided to remove the OAuth application access via Github. Still, after I've done this, if I try to access `localhost:8080` via Google Chrome, Chrome redirects me to `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client_id_here>` page (with a proper client id added). What can I do to remove this redirect? Ideally I'd like `localhost:8080` to take me to the Jenkins dashboard as it used to... :(

Comment: localhost:8080 -> Jenkins -> Github, so github need your login and authorization. You didn't move the OAuth access completely.

Comment: Right, so... How do I do that?

Comment: Remove the Github OAuth Plugin from your Jenkins and restart Jenkins.

Comment: Assuming Jenkins is what's listening on 8080, it sounds like the OAuth process might not have completed properly and Jenkins keeps trying to start it up again. A complete OAuth transaction typically goes Jenkins -> GitHub -> User auth -> Jenkins. If that last step, the redirect to Jenkins, fails then the transaction isn't done. What did you provide for your callback URL?

Comment: Owen Cao: Right, so how do I do this if I can't access the Jenkins main page? Is it possible to do it from e.g. command line or similar?
Chris: the wrong thing I'm afraid, which I realized after... Basically the same URL as the main location of the application. :(

Comment: @AndreasJohansson, can you stop the Jenkins service and restart it, then correct the callback URL? Also, this almost certainly doesn't have anything to do with Chrome, but you should be able to test that by using a different browser.

Comment: @Chris I've tried to restart the service but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [this may let you fix your problem](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security):

> One may accidentally set up security realm / authorization in such a
>   way that you may no longer able to reconfigure Jenkins.
>
> When this happens, you can fix this by the following steps:
>
> 1. Stop Jenkins (the easiest way to do this is to kill the servlet container.)
> 2. Go to `$JENKINS_HOME` in the file system and find `config.xml` file.
> 3. Open this file in the editor.
> 4. Look for the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` element in this file.
> 5. Replace `true` with `false`
> 6. Remove the elements `authorizationStrategy` and `securityRealm`
> 7. Start Jenkins
>
> When Jenkins comes back, it's in the unsecured mode where everyone
>   gets full access to the system.
>
> If this is still not working, trying renaming or deleting `config.xml`.

Once you get in, uninstall or reconfigure the GitHub OAuth plugin using the Jenkins UI, [re-enable security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup), and try again!

Comment: Fantastic, renaming the config.xml file finally worked. Thanks a lot! :)